# How to manage .json response data from custom REST in jhipster

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, spring, rest

I'm creating a new custom RESTful web service (managed with Spring framework) on a Jhipster app that search on objects **Request** containing a text that I give in input.

I tested the REST call from html and Angular.js and it works fine. The only one problem is that I don't know how could I parse the result in a html page instead of .json format.

My html code (located in "**src/main/webapp/app/layouts/navbar/navbar.html**") that call REST is this:

```
<form class="navbar" method="GET" action="/api/search">
    <input style="margin-top: 2.8%; margin-right:2px;" class="btn" type="text" name="content" placeholder="Search requests..." />
    <input style="margin-top: 2.8%; margin-right:5px;" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" text="Search" value="Search">
</form>
```

My "**navbarController.js**" is this:

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular
            .module('businessRequestApp')
            .controller('NavbarController', NavbarController);

    NavbarController.$inject = ['$state', 'Auth', 'Principal', 'ProfileService', 'LoginService', 'Request'];

    function NavbarController($state, Auth, Principal, ProfileService, LoginService, Request) {

        var vm = this;
        vm.isNavbarCollapsed = true;
        vm.isAuthenticated = Principal.isAuthenticated;

        ProfileService.getProfileInfo().then(function (response) {
            vm.inProduction = response.inProduction;
            vm.swaggerEnabled = response.swaggerEnabled;
        });

        vm.login = login;
        vm.logout = logout;
        vm.toggleNavbar = toggleNavbar;
        vm.collapseNavbar = collapseNavbar;
        vm.$state = $state;
        vm.requests = [];

        loadAll();

        function loadAll() {
            Request.query(function (result) {
                vm.requests = result;
                vm.searchQuery = null;
            });
        }

        function login() {
            collapseNavbar();
            LoginService.open();
        }

        function logout() {
            collapseNavbar();
            Auth.logout();
            $state.go('home');
        }

        function toggleNavbar() {
            vm.isNavbarCollapsed = !vm.isNavbarCollapsed;
        }

        function collapseNavbar() {
            vm.isNavbarCollapsed = true;
        }

    }
    })();
```

My java REST ("**RequestResource.java**") is this:

```
@GetMapping("/search")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<List<Request>> searchRequest(@RequestParam String content) {
    log.debug("REST request to get Request : {}", content);
    List<Request> requestsFounded = findByContentContaining(content);
    return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(Optional.ofNullable(requestsFounded));
}
```

When I click the button I receive this .json (that is a list of matching **Request** that I searched for - based on parameter **content** give in input):

```
[ {
  "id" : 13,
  "requestTitle" : "Titolo",
  "content" : "Richiesta",
  "creationDate" : "2017-06-23",
  "authorUsername" : "admin",
  "author" : null,
  "referencedTable" : {
    "id" : 3,
    "usersOnIt" : "",
    "name" : "Tavolo 1"
  }
}, {
  "id" : 14,
  "requestTitle" : "Voglio vedere Tiziano Ferro",
  "content" : "Mi piacerebbe vedere tiziano per fare ...",
  "creationDate" : "2017-06-25",
  "authorUsername" : "admin",
  "author" : null,
  "referencedTable" : {
    "id" : 4,
    "usersOnIt" : "alfa",
    "name" : "Tavolo 3"
  }
}, {
  "id" : 19,
  "requestTitle" : "Titolo",
  "content" : "Voglio vedere Marco",
  "creationDate" : "2017-06-26",
  "authorUsername" : "user",
  "author" : null,
  "referencedTable" : null
} ]
```

So, my final question is: how could I translate that .json objects list into an html table?
I've been searching a lot on the web but I found nothing, I hope someone will help me.

Thanks in advice for your time,
Manuel.

Comment: You get the above json when you click the search value inside your form based on your content input?

Comment: When I click the button I get a blank page that shows only that json string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a function on form submit and get the json in your vm instance inside your function

**HTML**

```
    <form class="navbar" ng-submit="vm.getJson()">
            <input style="margin-top: 2.8%; margin-right:2px;" class="btn" type="text" name="content" ng-model="vm.content" placeholder="Search requests..." />
            <input style="margin-top: 2.8%; margin-right:5px;" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" text="Search" value="Search">
        </form>
    <tr ng-repeat="value in json"><td>{{value }}</td></tr>
```

**JS**:

```
vm.getJson=function(){
  $http.get("YourUrl",vm.content).then(function(response){
  vm.json=response.data;
 console.log(response);
})
}
```

Comment: Ok, the reference works. I get code 500 due to "Required String parameter 'content' is not present" how could I give it with angular?

Comment: Are you sure your API is a get method? I think you have to send the content you searched to your API call, and get the matched result for that scenario.

Comment: I'm trying to do that in this way: `$http.get("/api/search?content=" + $scope.content).then(function (response) {
                vm.json = response.data;
                console.log(response);
            });` in thml I added to input text a ng-model="content" where "content" in .js is $scope.content but the issue is the same

Comment: Ok, i fixed it. I had to inject $scope too. Thanks a lot for your help, have a nice day!

Comment: Glad that I could be of help. :)